# Do I need new namespace if I added non-required element to data contract?

Tags: wcf, web-services

WCF: Do I need a new namespace if I added non-required element to data contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. With non requirement element your service is still backward compatible with old clients and there is no need to create new namespace and new contract version (unless you want strict versioning).